# C# Winforms Datagridview font is getting bolded when scaling to 150%

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts, datagridview, scaling

I've got a datagridview which displays information and also has some input columns. When using 100%, 125% and 175% resolution, the texts looks normal and is not thick. (image example 1). When changing to 150%, the headers and the text of the datagridview gets this strange bold and I can't seem to figure out why. Any suggestions? Thank you !

[Example #1 (this is how it looks on 100%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8LfG.png)

[Example #2 : this is where it gets bolded.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHfIU.png)
When scaling to 150%, the rest of the text in the form looks normal, and I use the same font in the form as well as in the datagridview.
[Example #3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YmRL.png)
[Example #4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGrQt.png)

I tried setting the CellStyle (header/general) to null, making the font smaller and still no results.

Comment: Create a new project with a new form and a new datagridview and check if it behaves that way also. If not check everything you changed from the defaults in the actual project. We can just guess from here what that could be.

Comment: You have to specify (always) the .NET version in use, whether your application is DpiAware and the scale mode (Font, DPI, custom)